# Why doesn't Python 2.x's write() function return the number of bytes written?

Tags: python

I'm most interested in the design decision that led to Python 2.x's write() function returning None instead of the number of bytes written.  It would imply some different mental model for the File object -- that it's not just a lightweight wrapper around a UNIX file descriptor.

Here's the documentation I'm referring to: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.write

Comment: UNIX isn't the only operating system that Python runs on.

Comment: What OS are you looking at? On linux to doc says: Help on built-in function write in module posix:

write(...)
    write(fd, string) -> byteswritten
    
    Write a string to a file descriptor.

Comment: He's looking at the `write` method of the `file` type.

Comment: this appears to have changed between python 2 and 3.

Comment: @Keith yeah, even though we have non-UNIX Python, we have functions like file.fileno() and file.isatty() in the standard lib, so assuming UNIX compatibility is reasonable.

Comment: Oh, then you are looking at the file object write method. FYI, this is not a thin wrapper on an fd. It is a wrapper on fwrite and C FILE object. But yes, odd that taht one doesn't return a value when fwrite does.

Answer (score 1):

From Python official Manual 3.2.2:-

```
write(b)
```

> **Write the bytes or bytearray object, b and return the number of bytes
>   written.** When in non-blocking mode, a BlockingIOError is raised if the
>   buffer needs to be written out but the raw stream blocks.

Comment: Only applies to Python 3.x, so I've updated the question to refer to Python 2.x and it's documentation.

Comment: In that case, doesn't this mostly answer the question? If it was changed in the latest version of Python, there's not much reason to examine why it wasn't the case in previous versions (any more than speculating why there weren't dictionary comprehensions before 2.7)